# Azure Active Directory B2C, case sensitive

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an issue with Azure AD B2C with pre-created user profiles and external IDP.
The account email is created in lowercase in AD B2C, but from the external IDP, the email claim is in camel casing. (Yes I know the email should be stored in lower case)
The mapping between the email claim from external IDP and the email address on the ADB2C account is case-sensitive, which causes problems.

This can be solved using a custom policy, but we are using the standard configuration in this case.

So is there a solution for mapping claims non-case sensitive between external IDP and ADB2C user accounts, with standard configuration?

/Jonas

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any in a standard user flow.

If you are using custom policy, you can resolve it by using `partnerClaimType` as below.

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="preferred_username" />
```